# PHP MySQL, data not returned, even though it is in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So the project I'm working on is built on the Cloud9 development platform, and I've hit a problem. This specific MySQL query is missing one of it's column data's, it just refuses to return it.

Part of my login code, with query;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmx9O.png

in code:

```
$sql_command = "SELECT Salt FROM User WHERE Name ='" . $username . "';";
    $result = $conn->query($sql_command);

    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        //echo "<p> username: ". $username . "</p>";
        //echo "<p> password: ".$password . "</p>";

        $salt = $result->fetch_array()[0];

        //echo "<p>salt " . $salt . "</p>";
        $hashed_password =  hash("sha256", $salt . $password);

        $sql_command = "SELECT `ID`, `Status` FROM User WHERE Password ='" . $hashed_password .
                        "' AND Name = '" . $username . "';";
        $result = $conn->query($sql_command);

        //echo $hashed_password;
        if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {

            $user = $result->fetch_array()[0];
            $status = $result->fetch_array()[1];

            if($status != -1)
            {
                $_SESSION['login_user'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['login_status'] = $status;
                $_SESSION['login_user_name'] = $username;
            }
```

data in question, Status column;

http://puu.sh/ec3fP/de1e63b384.png

The only column, that doesn't return any data, is the Status column.

Every other query works fine.

The column status is a int type, with 11 length. No other special characteristics.

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: I would suggest a different approach altogether.  Why have to queries against the DB to compare password.  Why not just select all columns you need based on username at once and then do your comparison.  There is no need to break this up into two separate queries.  You also may want to consider using PHP's built in `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions to avoid having to store the salt separately in the DB table.

Comment: Did you try alternatively selecting all (*) from the database and use a while?..
    While($result=fetch_array){
    $status=$result['Status'];
    echo $status;
    }
///This might be very random, what is your Code Editor? :D

Comment: The question you asked is incomplete, add a few more details to it!

Comment: Mostafa, Cloud9, as told in answer. Also helpful suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not refusing to fetch the array. It **DID** - you simply threw away the result:

This fetches a row:

```
  $user = $result->fetch_array()[0];
```

This fetches the **NEXT** row:

```
  $status = $result->fetch_array()[1];
```

Presumably your query will only ever return ONE row, so the second fetch will return a boolean false, signifying "no more data".

Your code should be:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array();
$user = $row[0];
$status = $row[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`$result->fetch_array()`, if run multiple times like you do it, will jump to the next row every time, hence it tries to fetch the status from the second row of your query result, which is nonexistent.

You could use e.g.

```
 $data = $result->fetch_array();
 $user = $data[0];
 $status = $data[1];
```

Comment: Thank you, this was it! Thank you for solving it, even though it may have been a simple hindsight on my part.